# Overloading and, or, not operators

Tags: postgresql, boolean, operators, overloading

I would like to overload the `AND`, `NOT` and `OR` operators for temporal booleans, i.e., boolean that varies on time.

When declaring

```
CREATE OPERATOR and (
    PROCEDURE = andMov,
    LEFTARG = booleanTP,
    RIGHTARG = boolean
);
```

I receive the error message

```
ERROR:  Syntax error near or at « and »
LINE 1: CREATE OPERATOR and (
                        ^
```

Obviously I can rename the operator to `andMov` or something else, but that would be less intuitive. I am using version 9.4.1 of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Would you mind adding the definition of `andMov` and `booleanTP` so this question makes sense beyond the syntax error? And *always* your version of Postgres. Also, to get English error messages run `SET lc_messages = 'C'` in your session

Answer (score 1):

In postgres (and in SQL in general) there are some "reserved" words that can not be "redefined". `and` is one of them.

Full list of reserved words: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html